# For some reason, I can't modify contents in USB drives

Tags: usb, permissions, chown

For some reason, only `root` can modify the contents in USB drives (create folder/file, etc.), after running related commands.

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly edited the permissions, or some command did.

I ran `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/$USER` (replace $USER with your username).

Comment: This will not work for NTFS or FAT drives which do not support Linux file permissions, and drives not mounted via the GUI in user space.  just saying.  (There are numerous other questions like this one which address those filesystem types)

Comment: I'm actually modifying the user's /media folder itself, not the drive, so I'm just telling the OS that the user is allowed to edit anything there. It did work for a FAT drive, of course the permissions weren't saved there.